# Aggregate sequential nodes using xpath in MessageConstruction shape

Tags: xpath, biztalk, biztalk-2010

I'm working with BizTalk 2010 and wondering about appending sequential elements in orchestration without mapping.

Lets say my orchestration receives **`Message_In`**:

```
<ns0:Employees xmlns:ns0="http://employee">
    <Employee>
        <FirstName>FirstName_1</FirstName>
        <LastName>LastName_1</LastName>
        <Age>1</Age>
    </Employee>
    <Employee>
        <FirstName>FirstName_2</FirstName>
        <LastName>LastName_2</LastName>
        <Age>2</Age>
    </Employee>
</ns0:Employees>
```

... and **`Message_Default`**:

```
<ns0:Employees xmlns:ns0="http://employee">
    <Employee>
        <FirstName>FirstName_Default</FirstName>
        <LastName>LastName_Default</LastName>
        <Age>0</Age>
    </Employee>
</ns0:Employees>
```

I wish to aggregate these messages to single **`Message_Out`**:

```
<ns0:Employees xmlns:ns0="http://employee">
    <Employee>
        <FirstName>FirstName_1</FirstName>
        <LastName>LastName_1</LastName>
        <Age>1</Age>
    </Employee>
    <Employee>
        <FirstName>FirstName_2</FirstName>
        <LastName>LastName_2</LastName>
        <Age>2</Age>
    </Employee>
    <Employee>
        <FirstName>FirstName_Default</FirstName>
        <LastName>LastName_Default</LastName>
        <Age>0</Age>
    </Employee>
</ns0:Employees>
```

If I try to simply assign default employees from `Message_Default` it replaces Employees node content. Is this possible to improve this statement somehow to append employees from `Message_Default` instead of replacing?

```
Message_Out = Message_In;
xpath(Message_Out, "/*[local-name()='Employees']") 
    = xpath(Message_Default, "/*[local-name()='Employees']/*[local-name()='Employee']");
```

*P.s. I know that I can achieve this with multi-message mapping, but I try to avoid mapping because of complicated structure of my real messages.*

Comment: You reference existing nodes with xpath.  This is not the tool to use.  If you really don't want to use mapping then I would consider writing a routine in C#, perhaps a dll and then reference it in your project.

Comment: I would honestly just go down the mapping route - it might be a complex map (based on your comment at the end of your post), however you'll be able to get results much quicker than appending in an Orchestration IMHO. If you are concerned about the complexity of a map, I would suggest that you take a look at using custom XSLT.